# How to get method and Quantity data from transactions per contract?

Tags: transactions

With the csv file of the transactions of a contract, there are two fields that do not return via api. They are: Quantity and Method.
Is there any way to get this data via API?

Comment: What csv file? What are Quantity and Method? What API are you talking about?

Comment: For example: https://etherscan.io/address/0x829 Budap24b016326a401d083b33d092293333a830

At the bottom of this page, you can download a csv file that comes with the quantity and method value.
These two values, I would like to consult via api.

Comment: The method can be determined from the input field of the transaction, similarly the value field is from the transaction. I don't use api, so I can't help you with that.